# TabHost selection tab when Back pressed

Tags: android

I have an Android app that uses TabHost. The problem is when I press back button in submenu of tab2 the app go to tab2. i want if Back Pressed, user go to tab 1, Please Help Me, thx
My TabHost Class :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    host = this.getTabHost();


    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one")
            .setIndicator("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home) )
            .setContent(new Intent(this, tab1.class))); 

    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two")
            .setIndicator("Master", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.master_data))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, tab2.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("tree")
            .setIndicator("P.O.S", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pos))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, tab3.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("four")
            .setIndicator("Report", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.report))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, tab4.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("five")
            .setIndicator("CSM", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transfer))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, tab5.class)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your tabHost

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(YourTabPosition);
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: where i put this to my script? please tell me complete step, thx

Comment: Can you provide your code so I can give you a better solution?

Comment: Use this:


    `@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        host.setCurrentTab(0);
    }`

This will always set your firs tab as current tab whenever you press back!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `public void setCurrentTab (int index)` but you have to override the back button default behavior.

```
public void onBackPressed ()
{
    if(host.getCurrentTab() == 1)
    {
        host.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
    else
    {
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: where i put this to my script? please tell me complete step, thx

Comment: i put this code to TabHost Class? in subTab i don't anything?

Comment: No. You put this in the Activity that manages your `TabHost`. You can override `onBackPressed` only inside an Activity. What do you mean with subTab?

Comment: My Tabhost like this, TabHost > tab1 > Master. I need user go to tab 2 if in Master back Pressed, can you help me please?